# Printing only decimal places of a number

Tags: c++

I was wondering how can you only print the decimal places of the number?
I need to print 10.30 as 10m,30cm and I have no idea how to do that.
I have tried to google the solution, but didn't find anything helpful.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <iomanip> 
using namespace std; 
int main() { 
    double P;
    cin >> P;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(0) << P << "m," << setprecision(2) << P << "cm";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your current codes?

Comment: Welcome to the Stack! The expectation on this site is that if you're looking for help with a problem, you need to show the effort you've made to try to solve it yourself. I'm going to vote to close the post, but if you edit in your own attempt to solve this problem, along with an explanation of what about your attempt isn't working, this question will be appropriate for the stack.

Comment: `#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main() {
double P;
cin>>P;
cout<<fixed<<setprecision(0)<<P<<"m,"<<setprecision(2)<<P<<"cm";
return 0;

}` i used this one, but i'm not sure how to print "30" instead of 10.30

Comment: Put it as part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a `double` `P`, and assuming you wanted to round half-way any fractions of `cm`, this is one approach:

```
unsigned long cm = std::round(P * 100); // ToDo - check the possibility of overflow
std::cout << cm / 100 << "m, " << cm % 100 << "cm";
```

Where I'm using integer arithmetic to extract the `m`, and modulo arithmetic to extract the `cm`. Enhance to handle negative `P` as required.